# How can i do transaction between remote services?

Tags: .net, transactions

I have to do 2 job which is on remote services not belongs to me.I have to register or upgrade a product on first remote service and i have to get payment via VPOS on second service.

Is it possible to make a kind of transaction in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether or not the remote services implements distributed transactions.  If it does not, you can't -- you will have to code around to try to compensate for the previous transaction.

If the other server runs something like MSDTC and you're connecting though a web service that supports WS-Transactions, you should just be able to wrap your call in a [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752261.aspx) object (from the System.Transactions assembly).  It's rare that application service providers to this, though.